# How does reference by classname.this.method works?

Tags: java, this

For example, I've got this code:

```
public class NewProjectModalWindow extends Window 
{
    private void initComponents() 
    {       
        cancel = new Button("Cancel");
        cancel.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                NewProjectModalWindow.this.close();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

How does `this` work in that case? I mean - how does it understand in the anonymous class that I want to call `close` method for exactly `this` instance of `NewProjectModalWindow`?

How is it able to find in the bunch of objects in the memory exactly my object by using `NewProjectModalWindow.this`?

How does `this` point out to the current instance?

Comment: "How is it able to find in the bunch of objects in the memory exactly my object by using NewProjectModalWindow.this?" - because object `A` creates an object `A$1` of the anonymous class `Button.ClickListener` where a one-to-many relationship is present and therefore every inner object knows its outer object.

Comment: Do you mean `Button.$1` or `NewProjectModalWindow.$1`?

Comment: Every object of `NewProjectModalWindow` creates its own inner anonymous implementation of `Button.ClickListener`.

Comment: Oh! So for another `NewProjectModalWindow` it will be something like `Button.ClickListener.$2` and `NewProjectModalWindow.$2`?

Comment: The anonymous class definition is the same, but the objects are each created new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NewProjectModalWindow.this` refers to the enclosing instance of your anonymous inner class, so it refers to the same instance in which the `Button.ClickListener` instance was created.

Here's the relevant [JLS entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.4) :

> 15.8.4. Qualified this
>
> Any lexically enclosing instance (§8.1.3) can be referred to by
>   explicitly qualifying the keyword this.
>
> Let T be the type denoted by TypeName. Let n be an integer such that T
>   is the n'th lexically enclosing type declaration of the class or
>   interface in which the qualified this expression appears.
>
> The value of an expression of the form TypeName.this is the n'th
>   lexically enclosing instance of this.
>
> The type of the expression is T.
>
> It is a compile-time error if the expression occurs in a class or
>   interface which is not an inner class of class T or T itself.

Comment: But how does it know that the current instance is an exactly this instance and not other instance of `NewProjectModalWindow`?

Comment: Each instance of `Button.ClickListener` is created by the `initComponents` method of an instance of `NewProjectModalWindow` and contains a reference to the instance that created it.

Comment: But how then `this` works? How does it understand that we need reference to the instance of the class in which the current `listener` was created?

Comment: @user1432980 The reference to the enclosing instance is implicitly passed to the constructor of the anonymous class. `NewProjectModalWindow.this` is the syntax to retrieve this reference.

Comment: Oh! I see. So basically it's something like specific syntax facility

Answer (score 1):

It is essentially just a hint to the compiler / interpreter to use the reference of the outer class in the nested class / method.

You could also store the reference to (`NewProjectModalWindow`)`this` in a (final) variable and use that in the nested class / method.

Answer (score 1):

this referes to implementations, implementations are usually at the top when defining the class or within an implemented method, in your case the ActionListener.

when you work with object oriented languages you create objects, but since the object ActionListener is an implementation you use `this` as an object referal, and in your case, it is in an implemnted method thus the `this` will refer to the called method which is "ActionListener"

you can also use `this` when it is like this:

```
public class MyClass implements ActionListener  //implemented


  public MyClass()
  {
   JButton btn = new JButton("Button");
   btn.addActionListener(this);  //refers to the class - which is implementing ActionListener
  }
```

you may come across `super` as well which is refered to the extended class.

**Simply put:**
It is a reference to the method or class that contains it.

read more about it here:
[How to use: this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

Answer (score 0):

Every instance of a non-static inner class in Java has a reference to an instance of the outer class. This reference is provided when an instance of the inner class is created. You can explicitly specify the outer-class instance when you create an instance of the inner class:

```
outerClassInstance.new InnerClass(...)
```

When you are in the scope of the outer class of this inner class, and you do not explicitly specify the outer class instance when creating the instance of the inner class (i.e. `new InnerClass(...)`), `this` is implicitly used (or `SomeOuterLevelClass.this`, if the immediate outer class is not the right type, where `SomeOuterLevelClass` is the innermost enclosing class that is the right type), as if you wrote `this.new InnerClass(...)`.

Now, what you have in your example is an anonymous class. An anonymous class, when created in a non-static scope, is a non-static inner class, so the stuff above applies (it has a reference to an instance of the outer class), except that you cannot explicitly specify an instance of the outer class when creating an instance of an anonymous class; it is forced to be `this`.